# Fatal error: Class 'Craft\FileCache' not found when trying to install

Tags: error-message, install, apache

I've been trying to install Craft on a DigitalOcean server. I used DO's LAMP stack application on Ubuntu 14.04 and downloaded the latest version of Craft. After uploading everything to my web root (the default is /var/www/html so the craft folder is at /var/www and the contents of public are at /var/www/html), whenever I try and go to the website, I get an error saying: `"Fatal error: Class 'Craft\FileCache' not found in /var/www/craft/app/services/CacheService.php on line 59"`. If I go to example.com/admin, I get an Apache 404 error. If I try example.com/index.php/admin, I get the same fatal error as I described above.

I know this means I need to enable mod_rewrite (I've already renamed htaccess to .htaccess), but I should still be seeing something. I'm not sure what to do about the fatal error. I've redownloaded the Craft files to be sure nothing got corrupted in the original download, but I still have the same problem. I've also tried it on a server I have from A Small Orange and got the same thing. I also changed the required folders' permissions to 777 just to rule out any permissions problems.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: It definitely sounds like a missing file from the error message.  Does `craft/app/etc/cache/FileCache.php` exist?

Answer (score 4):

After checking out the craft/app/etc folder, I noticed the cache folder was missing. It turns out that the problem was with my FTP client ignoring folders named "cache". So really a dumb mistake on my part.

Thanks for your help @BradBell!

Comment: Hah... glad that's all it was. Have also seen that happen when people deploy via Git and they have `cache` in their `.gitignore` file.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add that I got bitten by the same bug only I add to also retrieve the cache folder inside /craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Cache from my local install in order for things to start working.
Pretty weird this :)